# When can string slice `&str` produced by a function be returned in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've managed to cook up three scenarios which to me seem on the surface to be the same, but behave differently, and I would appreciate if someone could clarify to me why...

The first scenario fails to complile, as I would actually expect :

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = get_data();
    println!("{}", data);
}

fn get_data() -> &'static str {
    let x: String = String::from("hello");
    return x.as_str(); // always fails with ownership issue
}
```

Fails as expected: `returns a reference to data owned by the current function`

However the next two confound me given the above expectation:

This succeeds:

```rust
fn get_data() -> &'static str { // requires `'static` lifetime
    let x = std::path::Path::new("thing");
    match x.to_str() {
        None => "",
        Some(s) => s,
    }
}
```

I would have thought `s` was owned in the function so couldn't be returned, but in this case, adding `&'static str` as return type (compiler is unhappy otherwise) allows the operation.

More puzzlingly still, the following works (compiler is happy), and does *not* require the `'static` lifetime:

```rust
use std::path::Path;

pub fn parent_of(caller_file: &str) -> &str { // `'static` not required ??
    let caller_file_p: &Path = Path::new(caller_file);

    match caller_file_p.parent() {
        None => if caller_file.starts_with("/") { "/" } else { "." },
        Some(p) => match p.to_str() {
            None => {
                eprintln!("Bad UTF-8 sequence specified : '{}'", caller_file);
                std::process::exit(100);
            },
            Some(s) => s,
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's some methodical explanation as to the nuances of each scenario, but it eludes me. Clarifications most appreciated.

Comment: For the second case I'd ask "is `s` owned by the function or is `"thing"` a static string" and for the third "is the difference you're starting with a str reference?".  I suspect your confusion is from your expectation of `Path` generating new strings, but `Path::new` takes a reference and your return type scenarios are consistent with a function returning transformation over the original string, not creating something new and not where the function is holding onto something.

Comment: [`Path::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.new) constructs an `&Path`, which inherits the lifetime of the `&str` it was constructed from.

Comment: `Path` is to `PathBuf`, what `str` is to `String`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second case, you convert a `&'static str` (a string literal) to `&Path` via [`Path::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.new). `Path::new()` preserves the lifetime of the reference (because `Path` is not an owned type, but is a borrowed type that is basically some wrapper around the bytes owned by someone else, be it a [`PathBuf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html), a `String`, or the binary itself in case of a string literal). So you get `&'static PathBuf`. Converting it back to `&str` via [`Path::to_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.to_str) you get `&'static str`.

In the third case, you have string literals (`&'static str`s) and `&Path` with the lifetime of `caller_file`. If we annotate the lifetimes:

```rust
pub fn parent_of<'caller_file>(caller_file: &'caller_file str) -> &'caller_file str {
    // `'static` not required ??
    let caller_file_p: &'caller_file Path = Path::new(caller_file);

    match caller_file_p.parent() {
        None => {
            if caller_file.starts_with("/") {
                "/" // `&'static str`
            } else {
                "." // `&'static str`
            }
        }
        Some(p) => match p.to_str() {
            None => {
                eprintln!("Bad UTF-8 sequence specified : '{}'", caller_file);
                std::process::exit(100);
            }
            Some(s) => s, // `s` is `&'caller_file str`
        },
    }
}
```

The return type's lifetime is assumed to be `'caller_file` via the [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#lifetime-elision) rules. The string literals `"/"` and `"."` are `&'static str`, and since `'static` is greater than (or equal to) any lifetime, they can be shrinked to `&'caller_file str`. `caller_file_p` is `&'caller_file Path`, and its `to_str()` is `&'caller_file str`, so this works as expected.

Comment: Thank you - that does make sense. I couldn't quite see how the compiler was associating `caller_str`'s lifetime with what I assumed was a newly-created &str` from `to_str()` , but knowing the `Path::new()` isn't itself an owned type makes reasoning on this show (thanks to this answer and _possum_'s comment).

Answer (score 4):

@Chayim Friedman has already provided a correct answer but, seeing that there is an other answer which contains some misconceptions. I will therefore add some details about various usages of the word static in Rust to clarify the existing answer.

#### Literals

Literals are the builtin constructors of the builtin types. These include (among others) numbers, strings (as in `&str`), and tuples/arrays of those literals. All the types of the values that are literals have a `'static` lifetime (we'll come back on this later on).

#### `static` values

All binaries have some pre-allocated memory inside the binary itself, the size of which is written within the binary itself. This memory region is allocated with `static` items in Rust. The type of the values stored in those memory regions is necessarily `'static`, since they live as long as the program runs, just like literals.

However, these values are not necessarily literals: the compiler must be able to evaluate the content of this memory region at compile time. Literals can all be computed at compile-time (as there is nothing to compute), but in general all `const` expressions can be put there too.

In fact, in general, a literal is *not* allocated as a `static` value. Most likely, a literal such as `3` will be compiled to an assembly instruction that produces that literal where it is required to be (if not further optimized). It is not created at load-time, and then copied all other the places. **But** thanks to [static promotion](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.html), a literal (and other values too) can be promoted as a `static` value, that is, it *will* be allocated within the binary, and that allocated region will be pointed to/copied when necessary. The compiler automatically does that when a `static` value is required.

#### `'static` lifetime bound

Certain types `T` are bound by a `'static` lifetime, which is written in Rust as `T: 'static`. This **does not mean that any value `x` of type `T` will live as long as the rest of the program**, or even that it is possible to borrow a such a value for `'static` (ie. `&'static x`). In fact, most local variables (ie. that are created when a function is called, and which do not exist anymore after that function is left) have a type that is static. Consider the following:

```rust
fn assert_static<T: 'static>(x: T) -> T { x }

fn example() {
    // literal, that may or may not be a static value
    let x = assert_static(3);
    // `x` is bound by a 'static lifetime, but it lives at most for the scope of the function `example`
    let x = assert_static(x);
    // this expression is not computable at compile time, it is allocated on the heap
    // and will not live forever, yet it is bound by a 'static lifetime
    let x = assert_static(String::from("hello"));
    
    // the following fails, because while the type of x is bound by a 'static lifetime, it does not have a 'static lifetime, so x cannot be borrowed for 'static
    // let y: &'static _ = &x;
}
```

A way to think of values whose type is bound by a `'static` lifetime is values that *could* live forever from now on. They do not necessarily exist at the beginning of the execution of the program, and do not necessarily exist until the end.

The reason that the last borrow is illegal is that while the value stored in `x` has a `'static` lifetime, `x` itself cannot live forever. There is no such thing as a lifetime for variables (at least, not exposed to the programmer) but the idea is that at any point in time, I could move the value out of `x` and that particular value could live forever, but `x` itself cannot live forever so any reference to the value stored in `x` *through* x is restricted to live at most as long as `x` does. This is typically what `Box::leak` does.

This is also the reason why the first example fails to compile, but not the second.

Comment: Having a static lifetime is not written as `T: 'static` that's a lifetime bound. The object behind a `'static` reference does have a lifetime of `'static` however, since that reference has to be valid for the whole programs duration (any one having it can access it for that long) that means the object behind it has to have a lifetime of `'static` and has to live until the end of the program. I was not very precise in my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77149164/#comment136007851_77149782)

Comment: @cafce25 `T: 'static` is indeed a lifetime bound, but it is equivalent to saying `T` has a static lifetime (AFAIK) because there is no greater lifetime than `'static`. As for the reference, it seems to me that you are saying the same thing as I say in the paragraph with "[`x: T` and `T: 'static` does not imply] that it is possible to borrow [`x`] for `'static` (ie. `&'static x`)" (but the converse is obviously true), but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: No having a bound of `'static` is not the same as having static lifetime, that's precisely my point. See the first of the common misconception corollaries of [Common Rust lifetime misconceptions 2.](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md/#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program)

Comment: @cafce25 it must be the sixth time I read that paragraph, and yet I evidently still haven't understood it thoroughly: life is hard :') more seriously, if I've understood correctly, having a lifetime of `'a` means that `'a` is the actual lifetime the compiler computed for a certain value/variable/type, whereas being bound by a lifetime `'a` is just a constraint that the Rust programmer writes, right? But then, which one of the three above  (value/variable/type) is correct for that sentence?

Comment: The lifetimes we can use always refer to a value at a specific memory location (those on references) or to the possible lifetime of a value (lifetime bounds).

Answer (score -1):

The string of characters of "hello" are stored somewhere in the binary of the program when it is compiled, and so always exist when the program is running. This is exactly what it means to have a static lifetime.

Thus one way to make your first version work is to write it like so:

```rust
fn get_data() -> &'static str {
    let x: &'static str = "hello";
    return x;
}
```

which actually is more idiomatically written as:

```rust
fn get_data() -> &'static str {
    "hello"
}
```

In your version, you create a new `String`, which copies these characters to some location on the heap and gives you a handle to that location and some information about how much space is used and is still available. But it is important to note that this handle owns this memory and when the handle goes away the memory location is no longer valid.

Thus another way to make your first version work is to write it like so:

```rust
fn get_data() -> String {
    "hello".to_string()    
}
```

But instead of returning the owning handle, you create a borrowing handle and let the owning handle drop.

```rust
fn get_data() -> &'static str {
    let x: String = String::from("hello"); // create owning handle
    return x.as_str(); // return borrowing handle
    // owning handle drops and memory is invalid to access using borrowing handle
}
```

To understand why the other two functions work, you should think about why these work:

```rust
fn get_data() -> &'static str {
    "hello"
}

fn pass_on_data(s: &str) -> &str {
    s
}
```

Comment: A `'static` lifetime does not mean memory is located somewhere within the binary that's trivially not true for anything leaked for example with `Box::leak`. It means that the reference is valid until the end of the program.

Comment: @cafce25, you are correct. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: Having a static lifetime is *not* the same as living for the whole execution of the program, which is also *not* the same as being stored in the binary, which is also *not* the same as being a literal. These are common misconceptions in Rust, I'll add an answer to this question to clarify this point.

Comment: @jthulhu, I agree with that, but none of these differences seem to matter for this case.